# WAMPserver 3.3.0 - need VH shown on LAN computers?

Tags: wamp, virtualhost

I have installed WAMP 3.3.0 for a local only "intranet" for computers on my LAN only to access the intranet.  When I access my IP of 192.168.. on another computer i'm getting the default WAMP homepage and not my "intranet" VirtualHost?  Any help?  This is my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
    # Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName intranet
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/new"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/new/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#
```

Comment: So I've changed the port of localhost to 81 and now the BVH does show BUT now I can't access my WAMP server homepage?  Is this even possible with 2 port 80's in the VH conf?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was having both "hosts" on port 80.  So i put my Virtual Host on port 8080 and than had to edit the httpd.conf file to "listen" to that port.  I now have both running. Localhost is just for my system and the VH is for the LAN using the IP address with :8080 behind it.

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:8080
```